# Display Minutes and seconds only displays 0

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I need help with the last part of my time difference script it displays 0 min, 0 seconds I'm hoping someone can resolve this for me please.

```
mu is MembershupUser
PrintTimeSpan1(DateTime.Now - mu.LastActivityDate);

public string PrintTimeSpan1(TimeSpan p)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (p.Days > 365)
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} yr, ", (int)Math.Floor(p.TotalDays / 365));
    if (p.Days % 365 > 30) 
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} months, ", (p.Days % 365) / 30);
    if (p.Days % 365 % 30 > 7)
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} weeks, ", p.Days % 365 % 30 / 7);
    if (p.Days % 365 % 30 % 7 > 0)
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} days, ", p.Days % 365 % 30 % 7);
    if (p.Hours > 0)
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} hrs, ", p.Hours);
    if (p.Minutes > 0)
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} mins, ", p.Minutes);
    if (p.Seconds > 0)
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} seconds ,", p.Seconds); 
    if (sb.Length > 2)
    {
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 2, 2); // remove the last ", " part. 
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's with the `% 59`? Minutes contains the number of minutes, and Seconds contains the number of seconds. That should be all you need.

If you had to calculate the remainder, shouldn't it be `% 60`? But why is that needed here at all?

```
if (p.Minutes > 0)
    sb.AppendFormat("{0} mins, ", p.Minutes);
if (p.Seconds > 0)
    sb.AppendFormat("{0} seconds ,", p.Seconds);
```

Note that TotalMinutes and TotalSeconds contain the number of minutes and seconds in the entire time span. But Minutes and Seconds just return the minutes and seconds portion of that time span.

Comment: i didn't mean to put that there. it doesn't display seconds or minutes do you know how to fix this

Comment: I tried you're version and i still get a blank space nothing shows

Comment: Well, you posted some code but then said you didn't mean to "put that there", and now you've changed it. So what you have now is a mystery to me. What's the code? Do you know how to use the debugger? What are the values?

Comment: I went through the debugger and it returns an empty stringbuilder object i updated my code to reflect the changes

Comment: Also, if you just read the membership user, the last activity date may have been updated so that it is equal to now and your time span is zero. If you learn to use the debugger, detecting cases like that is very easy.

Comment: Where is your case to build a result string if the time span is less than a second?

Comment: I checked the time difference and they are in sync together so there is no differnece